# Spring: How to check programmatically if given endpoint is secured

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using Spring Boot and Oauth2 for Spring Security and I want to check if given API endpoint is accessible for all users.

Sample Oauth configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {

        //(...)

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/logout**", "/denied**", "/index**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/ma/**", "/maintenance/**", "/api/maintenance/**")
                        .permitAll()
//                      .hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers("/api/**")
                        .permitAll()
//                      .hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
                    .anyRequest()
                        .denyAll()
                .and()
                    .exceptionHandling()
                        .accessDeniedPage("/denied")
                .and()
                    .csrf()
                        .disable();
        }

        //(...)
}
```

How do I check programmatically if, for example, enpoint `/api/someMethod` is available for all (is registered with `.permitAll()`)?
Is there simple way to do so even if I'm using basic or digest authorization?

Comment: Even if the controller method is accessible, there can be Secured annotation on Service as well as DAO layer of the webapp. For such annotation, if the condition is not satisified, that method is not called, and you won't even know.

Comment: I'm not using `@Secured` annotation if this helps somehow.

Comment: Then I don't understand your question, because if your security is limited till the Controller methods, then all of them which you have not mentioned in your security config, are insecure methods, by deduction.

Comment: `then all of them which you have not mentioned in your security config, are insecure methods` I don't think so, there is `.anyRequest()` that 'catches' every other enpoint that wasn't configured after all.

Comment: Yes, that's only because you have explicitly mentioned denyAll. And I still don't know why you want a list of methods for your own webapp.

Comment: There is several version of the application however they differ in some ways (some enpoints can be accessible for all or you have to have ROLE_ADMIN privilege) and I want to programmatically check in one point if user can make safe calls to these endpoint that won't end with bad looking 403 status code. I hope I made it a little more clearer.

Comment: That's why I can't be sure if given endpoint for given application is available or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a test that asserts the outcome of requesting a given path. There's a whole section in the Spring Security user guide: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/reference/htmlsingle/#test. The focus there is on using `MockMvc`.

Or you can run a full stack integration test including a real HTTP call. Example:

```
@Test
public void testHome() throws Exception {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML));
    ResponseEntity<String> entity = new TestRestTemplate().exchange(
            "http://localhost:" + this.port, HttpMethod.GET,
            new HttpEntity<Void>(headers), String.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.FOUND, entity.getStatusCode());
    assertTrue("Wrong location:\n" + entity.getHeaders(),
            entity.getHeaders().getLocation().toString().endsWith(port + "/login"));
}
```