# How to write unit test for SecurityConfig for spring security

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security, auth0

I have a class for spring security, validating token from the user. I got the code from Auth0 website and modified `antMatcher` part for my configuration. Here is the code:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
        This is where we configure the security required for our endpoints and setup our app to serve as
        an OAuth2 Resource Server, using JWT validation.
        */
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/data/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/data/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_data:write")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().cors()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        /*
        By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token, to ensure that this token is
        indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
        */
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator =
                new com.nuance.pindata.health.importer.security.AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

I am now trying to write unit test, but there is no good way to test it. I can practically test changing method/path, but it is not straight forward how to write this unit test, and it can be done through integration (automation) tests.

From [Spring Security HttpSecurity Configuration Testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43663688/spring-security-httpsecurity-configuration-testing), he suggests not writing unit test for such security config as well. What is the right approach here? If I should write unit test, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you wanting to test the JwtDecoder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can test actuator endpoints access-control in integration tests only (`@SpringBootTest`). For your own secured `@Components`, you can do it also in unit-tests (many samples in [this repo](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)):

- `@Controller` with `@WebMvcTest` (`@WebfluxTest` if you were in a reactive app)
- plain JUnit with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)`, `@EnableMethodSecurity` and `@Import` of the tested component (`@Service` or `@Repository` with method security like `@PreAuthorize` expressions) to get an autowired instance instrumented with security

`spring-security-test` comes with some MockMvc request post-processors (see `org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt` in your case) as well as WebTestClient mutators (see `org.springframework.security.test.web.reactive.server.SecurityMockServerConfigurers.mockJwt`) to configure Authentication of the right type (`JwtAuthenticationToken` in your case) and set it in test security context, but this is limited to MockMvc and WebTestClient and as so to `@Controller` tests.

Sample usage in an integration test (`@SpringBootTest`) for actuator to be up (but you get the idea for unit-tests):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
import static org.springframework.security.test.web.servlet.request.SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.jwt;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetLiveness_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/actuator/health/liveness"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetMachin_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsGrantedWithDataWrite_whenGetMachin_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/machin")
                .with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_data:write"))))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAuthenticatedButNotGrantedWithDataWrite_whenGetMachin_thenForbidden() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/machin")
                .with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.authorities(List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_openid"))))))
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
}
```

You might also use `@WithMockJwtAuth` from [this libs I maintain](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons). This repo contains quite a few samples for unit and integration testing of any kind of `@Component` (`@Controllers` of course but also `@Services` or `@Repositories` decorated with method-security).

Above Sample becomes:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-oauth2-test</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetLiveness_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/actuator/health/liveness"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsAnonymous_whenGetMachin_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth("SCOPE_data:write")
    void givenUserIsGrantedWithDataWrite_whenGetMachin_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth("SCOPE_openid")
    void givenUserIsAuthenticatedButNotGrantedWithDataWrite_whenGetMachin_thenForbidden() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/data/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
}
```

## Spring-addons starter

In the same repo as test annotations, you'll find starters to simplify your resource server security config (and also improve your CORS config and synchronize sessions and CSRF protection disabling as **the second should not be disabled with active sessions**...).

Usage is super simple and **all you'd have to change to switch to another OIDC authorization-server would be properties**. This could happen for instance because you are forced to by the busyness (if, they decide that Auth0 is too expensive or cannot be trusted anymore) or maybe because you find it is more convenient to use a standalone Keycloak on your dev machine (it is available offline, which I frequently am).

Instead of directly importing `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, import a thin wrapper around it ([composed of 3 files](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/webmvc/spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server) only):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.12</version>
</dependency>
```

By default, users must be authenticated to access any route but those listed in `com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all` property (see below). Replace all your Java conf with:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    // If not using method-security or to configure actuator RBAC
    // You might define a bean of type ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistryPostProcessor
    // and Fine tune AuthorizeHttpRequestsConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.AuthorizationManagerRequestMatcherRegistry
}
```

You can remove all `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver` properties, it is ignored (with an exception of `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences` if you validate audience). Properties to use instead are:

```
# Define this instead of auth0.audience
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences=http://localhost:8080,https://localhost:8080

# Single OIDC JWT issuer but you can add as many as you like
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://dev-ch4mpy.eu.auth0.com/

# Mimic spring-security default converter: map authorities with "SCOPE_" prefix
# Difference with your current conf is authorities source is not only "scope" claim but also "roles" and "permissions" ones 
# I would consider map authorities without "SCOPE_" prefix (the default behaviour of my starters) and update access control expressions accordingly
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=scope,roles,permissions
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.prefix=SCOPE_

# Fine-grained CORS configuration can be set per path as follow:
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/data/api/**
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowed-origins=https://localhost,https://localhost:8100,https://localhost:4200
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowedOrigins=*
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowedMethods=*
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].allowedHeaders=*
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].exposedHeaders=*

# Comma separated list of ant path matchers for resources accessible to anonymous
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/data/actuator/**
```

Bootyfool, isn't it?