# mockMvc cannot mock service for unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-security

I am writing a unit test for spring security and JWT validation. There are 3 basic cases I want to start the test with:

1. When no token -> expect 401
2. When token but wrong scope -> expect 403
3. When token and scope -> expect 200

I tested my code using postman and they return expected responses. In my unit test I have this:

```
@SpringBootTest
@ContextConfiguration(classes = SecurityConfig.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Import(DataImporterControllerConfig.class)
public class SecurityConfigTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    void doImportExpect200() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(put(URI).with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                "SCOPE_data:write"))).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(BODY)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
```

It does pass validation part and try to return some value from the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "${data.uriPrefix}")
@Loggable(value = INFO, trim = false)
public class DataImporterController {

    private final DataImporterService dataImporterService;

    @PutMapping(path = "/someurl", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public dataImportResponse doImport(@RequestHeader(name = ACCEPT, required = true) final String acceptHeader,
        final @RequestBody @NotBlank String body) {
        return new DataImportResponse(dataImporterService.doImport(body));
    }
```

The logic inside `dataImporterService.doImport(body)` require some db operation, so ideally, I want to mock it and make it return some value (something like `when(dataImporterServiceMock.doImport(body)).thenReturn(something)`.

However, when I try it, it doesn't work. I think it is because I am not creating a controller with mocked service. I tried to create one, but due to configuration for `SecurityConfig` class, it is not that easy. Here is SecurityConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
        This is where we configure the security required for our endpoints and setup our app to serve as
        an OAuth2 Resource Server, using JWT validation.
        */
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/actuator/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/dataimporter/**").hasAuthority("SCOPE_data:write")
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().cors()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        /*
        By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token, to ensure that this token is
        indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
        */
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

I got this code from Auth0 and just modified `antMatcher` portion. How can I test it so it returns 200 (mock service or something)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated in the answer to your other question ["How to write unit test for SecurityConfig for spring security"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340753/619830), **for unit-testing a `@Controller`, use `@WebMvcTest`** (with mocked dependencies), not `@SpringBootTest` which is intended for integration testing, loads much more config, and instantiate & autowire actual components (and, as a consequence, is slower and less focused)

```
@WebMvcTest(controllers = DataImporterController.class)
public class DataImporterControllerUnitTest {
    @MockBean
    DataImporterService dataImporterService;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() {
        when(dataImporterService.doImport(body)).thenReturn(something);
    }

    @Test
    void doImportExpect200() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(put(URI).with(jwt().authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                "SCOPE_data:write"))).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).accept(APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content(BODY)).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

If you had followed the [link I already provided](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons), you'd have find that in the main README, in [the many samples](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/webmvc-jwt-default/src/test/java/com/c4_soft/springaddons/samples/webmvc_jwtauthenticationtoken), and in [the tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken)

## Notes

> I am writing a unit test for spring security and JWT validation.

This are completely separate concerns and is to be done separately:

- spring security access-control is unit-tested with secured components: `@Controller` of course, but also `@Service`, `@Repository`, etc. where method-security is used (refer to your previous question for instructions and to my repo for samples)
- Authorization header is not considered when building `@WebMvcTest` or `@WebfluxTest` security-context. Authentication instances are built based on MockMvc request post-processors, WebTestClient mutators or annotations and **this does not involve any token decoding or validation**. JWT validation has to be tested in a `JwtDecoder` unit-test (only if you keep your own, which you shouldn't, see below)

> Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token

[This is wrong with spring-boot since 2.7](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/29084): `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences` property does just that. There is no need for you to override the `JwtDecoder` provided by spring-boot (actually, you shouldn't), and, as a consequence to unit-test your own.

> 1. When no token -> expect 401
> 2. When token but wrong scope -> expect 403
> 3. When token and scope -> expect 200

To be exact, the phrasing would better be:

- "anonymous" rather than "no token"
- "authenticated" rather than just "token"
- "authorities" rather than "scope"

The reason for that are:

- the OAuth2 token is validated and then turned into an `Authentication` instance: by default `AnonymousAuthenticationToken` if token is missing or validation fails, and whatever the configured authentication-converter returns if validation is successful
- spring-security **R**ole-**B**ased **A**ccess-**C**ontrol is completely generic (nothing specific to OAuth2) and relies on `GrantedAuthority`, not `scope`. This common confusion is due to the fact that there is nothing related to RBAC in OAuth2 nor OpenID standards and the default authentication-converter had to choose a claim that is always there to map authorities from. `scope` claim was picked as default, adding the `SCOPE_` prefix. You should refer to how RBAC is implemented by your own authorization server and provide an authentication-converter bean to map authorities from the right claim(s).

Auth0 uses `roles` and `permissions` claims when [RBAC is enabled](https://auth0.com/docs/manage-users/access-control/rbac), Keycloak uses `realm_access.roles` and `resource_access.{client-id}.roles`, etc., reason for me implementing a configurable authorities-converter, which picks the claims that should be used as authorities source from application properties (and how to map it: prefix and case transformation).

Last, your configuration is still risky (enabled sessions with disabled CSRF protection and poor CORS config). You should really consider using ["my" starters](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons#spring-boot-resource-server-starters), or follow the tutorial I wrote for [configuring a resource-server with just `spring-boot-oauth2-resource-server`](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/resource-server_with_jwtauthenticationtoken).

Comment: @jonathan-hagen see the notes I added