# How do I test main app without spring security?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, auth0

I have a main app that exposes endpoint like this. I have a test like this. It simply uses TestRestTemplate, calls actuator endpoint and checks health:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = HealthDataImporterApplication.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
public class HealthDataImporterApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
    @LocalServerPort
    private int serverPort;

    @Test
    public void health() {
        assertThat("status", read(get("health"), "$.status").equals("UP"));
    }

    private String get(final String resource) {
        return testRestTemplate.getForObject(String.format("http://localhost:%s/actuator/%s", serverPort, resource),
                String.class);
    }
}
```

I now added `SecurityConfig` class to add authentication to the app. Here is SecurityConfig class:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    private static final String ACTUATOR_URL = "/actuator/**";
    private static final String SCOPE_PREFIX = "SCOPE_";
    private static final String PERMISSION_SCOPE = "scope:scope";

    @Value("${auth0.audience}")
    private String audience;

    @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri}")
    private String issuer;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        /*
        This is where we configure the security required for our endpoints and setup our app to serve as
        an OAuth2 Resource Server, using JWT validation.
        */
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, ACTUATOR_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().hasAuthority(SCOPE_PREFIX + PERMISSION_SCOPE)
            .and().cors()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt();
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        /*
        By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token, to ensure that this token is
        indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
        */
        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);
        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer),
                new AudienceValidator(audience)));
        return jwtDecoder;
    }
}
```

Main app imports this `SecurityConfig` class so authentication is there. However, it fails the existing test because it complains it is missing `auth0.audience` and other value. It seems like it is trying to actually call auth0 url, which I don't want the test to. Otherwise, I have to put actual auth0 audience and domain which is sensitive data.

How can I disable spring security with TestRestTemplate? Is it worth to test this class at all?

Comment: You can enable and disable beans depending on the context using Spring Profiles. With it you can set up a different (or no) security configuration for testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using spring-boot, **do not override the JwtDecoder** just to check audiences. Use `spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.audiences` property instead (this is a comma separated list of acceptable audience).

Rather than deactivating security, I prefer to use mocked identities and include access-control in test coverage, using `MockMvc` (yes, even in `@SpringBootTest` with many components wired).

Refer to [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340753/619830) for details on how to do that in unit-test **and integration-test**.

Because I find request post-processors not that readable and I happen to unit-test secured components which are not controllers (like `@Service` or `@Respository` with method-security like `@PreAuthorize`, `@PostFilter`, etc.), I created a [lib with test annotations for OAuth2](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons):

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    // actuator
    @Test
    void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetStatus_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.get("/actuator/health")
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.status").value("UP"));
    }

    // secured resource
    @Test
    void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetMachin_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/api/v1/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth("SCOPE_openid", "SCOPE_scope:scope")
    void givenUserIsGrantedWithExpectedAuthority_whenGetMachin_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/api/v1/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockJwtAuth("SCOPE_openid")
    void givenUserIsNotGrantedWithExpectedAuthority_whenGetMachin_thenForbidden() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/api/v1/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
}
```

As comparison, the same sample with just `spring-security-test`:

```java
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class ApplicationIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc api;

    // actuator
    @Test
    void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetStatus_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/actuator/health/liveness"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    // secured resource
    @Test
    void givenRequestIsAnonymous_whenGetMachin_thenUnauthorized() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/api/v1/machin"))
            .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsGrantedWithExpectedAuthority_whenGetMachin_thenOk() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/api/v1/machin")
                .with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.authorities(List.of(
                        new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_openid"),
                        new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_scope:scope"))))))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    void givenUserIsNotGrantedWithExpectedAuthority_whenGetMachin_thenForbidden() throws Exception {
        api.perform(get("/api/v1/machin")
                .with(jwt().jwt(jwt -> jwt.authorities(List.of(
                        new SimpleGrantedAuthority("SCOPE_openid"))))))
            .andExpect(status().isForbidden());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In [JHipster](https://www.jhipster.tech), we generate a `TestSecurityConfiguration` class that mocks the `JwtDecoder` bean so no identity provider is needed. You can see the code [here](https://github.com/oktadev/auth0-full-stack-java-example/blob/main/src/test/java/com/auth0/flickr2/config/TestSecurityConfiguration.java). I've copied it below for your convenience.

```java
package com.auth0.flickr2.config;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.TestConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistration;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;

/**
 * This class allows you to run unit and integration tests without an IdP.
 */
@TestConfiguration
@Import(OAuth2Configuration.class)
public class TestSecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    ClientRegistration clientRegistration() {
        return clientRegistrationBuilder().build();
    }

    @Bean
    ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(ClientRegistration clientRegistration) {
        return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);
    }

    private ClientRegistration.Builder clientRegistrationBuilder() {
        Map<String, Object> metadata = new HashMap<>();
        metadata.put("end_session_endpoint", "https://jhipster.org/logout");

        return ClientRegistration
            .withRegistrationId("oidc")
            .issuerUri("{baseUrl}")
            .redirectUri("{baseUrl}/{action}/oauth2/code/{registrationId}")
            .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC)
            .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
            .scope("read:user")
            .authorizationUri("https://jhipster.org/login/oauth/authorize")
            .tokenUri("https://jhipster.org/login/oauth/access_token")
            .jwkSetUri("https://jhipster.org/oauth/jwk")
            .userInfoUri("https://api.jhipster.org/user")
            .providerConfigurationMetadata(metadata)
            .userNameAttributeName("id")
            .clientName("Client Name")
            .clientId("client-id")
            .clientSecret("client-secret");
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        return mock(JwtDecoder.class);
    }

    @Bean
    OAuth2AuthorizedClientService authorizedClientService(ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository) {
        return new InMemoryOAuth2AuthorizedClientService(clientRegistrationRepository);
    }
}
```

This class is then referenced in the test and overrides the `SecurityConfig`.

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = { Flickr2App.class, TestSecurityConfiguration.class })
```

The full project repo is at https://github.com/oktadev/auth0-full-stack-java-example.

Comment: This answers the questiion better than what I propose: the request is to deactivate security, but for a project template, keeping the access-control configured and including in test coverage with mocked identities seems a better option to me. Details there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75340753/619830