# How to mock JwtDecoder in Spring Boot for integration testing of authenticated controllers?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, integration-testing

In my Spring Boot application, there are some authenticated controllers.
The operation mode is "OAuth2 resource server", so my application relies on some arbitrary OAuth2 authorization server. (Let's say it's Keycloak, though it should not affect the way of mocking)

So, the question is:

**What is the right way to mock JwtDecoder, in order to be able to pass some static strings as the bearer tokens?**

(Please remember, it's a third party server responsible for the token issuing; So I cannot rely on it in tests. I want to mock it away to be able to run tests offline for example)

*An example of what I expect to happen:*

1. I mock JwtDecoder (let's pretend I've created some map of <token string, UserData>)
2. I make a MockMvc-based http call to the authenticated controller with this static string in the Authorization header (Authorization: Bearer STATIC_STRING). The controller test is decorated with `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc`.
3. I expect to have JwtAuthenticationToken filled with data from UserData from the map of the mocked JwtDecoder.

**I've already tried** to just create a bean of JwtDecoder implementation with all the described features. I see this bean is added to the configuration, but still whole test ends up in `AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext`. So I presume that JwtDecoder is never called (checked that with the debugger), and the whole testing setup is misconfigured, but I don't know for sure what to change.

What do I miss?

Comment: please dont describe your code, and instead show your code

Comment: @Toerktumlare please either share something valuable or don't engage otherwise

Comment: @ch4mp looks like it does!

Answer (score 1):

With `MockMvc` (as well as `WebTestClient` in reactive apps) the `Authorization` header is just ignored (not decoded, validated, introspected or whatever).

The test security context is to be set directly (`SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext().setAuthentication(auth);`) or with the help of either:

- test annotations (like `@WithMockUser`, but this one is not quite adapted to mocking OAuth2 identities). Refer to those that I created in [this lib for OAuth2](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons)
- Request post-processors for `MockMvc`
- mutators for `WebTestClients`

More details in this other answers:

- [How to write unit test for SecurityConfig for spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340149/how-to-write-unit-test-for-securityconfig-for-spring-security/75340753#75340753)
- [How do I test main app without spring security?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75376543/619830)

Comment: Looks like your library has a great PR campaign :) Anyway, it seems it does what I need. Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Actually, some from this library was integrated in `spring-security-test`: the OAuth2 MockMvc request post-processors and WebTestClient mutators come from there (look at author tag ;)