# How to automate the keycloak setup while running Junit test cases?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, keycloak

I have some Junit test cases in my Spring Boot project. I am using keycloak for getting tokens on the basis of the username and password in order to perform authentication. Now instead of manually deploying the keycloak server while running Junit test cases, I want to automate the keycloak deployment step. I want to ask that is there any Java library through which I can easily start the keycloak, pass the json file that contains all the configuration related to the realm, clients and users and then after running all Junit test cases keycloak automatically stops? Is there any way of doing such thing while running Junit test cases easily?

Answer (score 0):

If you start an external service, this are surely not unit-tests. This is not even integration testing. That's part of end-to-end testing.

With Spring Boot:

- the first (unit) are `@WebMvcTest` (or `@WebFluxTest` for reactive app) when testing a `@Controller` or plain JUnit with `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` to `@EnableMethodSecurity` and auto-wire an instrumented instance of the secured `@Component` (`@Service` or `@Repository` with `@PreAuthorise`, `@PostFilter` and alike). **All external service and all `@Components` (but the one under test) are mocked and so is the `Authentication` in the security-context**.
- the second (integration) are `@SpringBootTest` which wire together the application `@Components` (but external services are still mocked / stubbed). It is still possible to `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` (or `@AutoConfigureWebTestClient`) and as so, to keep using mocked `Authentication`.
- the last is best to be done without Java (Protractor or whatever end-to-end testing tool)

I answered this subject many times already. To mention a few:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75465772/619830
- [How to write unit test for SecurityConfig for spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75340149/how-to-write-unit-test-for-securityconfig-for-spring-security/75340753#75340753)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75376543/619830

Comment: actually, in my project there are some test cases that in which we hit multiple services that also need tokens. Also if unit tests need to access databases, we have written scripts to automatically install and download them and when unit tests stop, we remove them that's why I thought that like these scenarios, I should also automate all steps related to the keycloak deployment.

Comment: right now, I have used testcontainers for automatically deploying keycloak and then I simply import json file in it that has configuration about the realm, client and all the users.

Comment: I'd be curious how services use tokens. Doesn't it rather use spring-security `Authentication` instances in the security context? If you follow links, you'll figure out how to set security context for such components. Also only `@Repository` unit test should access database, otherwise, this is integration testing. Unit testing services (with mocked repos) is far more efficient & stable than writing extensive integration tests.